# Encrypt a link using php

Tags: php, javascript, html, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One time download liks in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329443/one-time-download-liks-in-php)

I am seeking for a solution for security on a link.

I would like to let the user to be able to click and get to the destinated url, but they won't be able to read the link from the source code, or maybe to generate a time limited url each time the user lands on the page, so each time the user logs in they will see a different url and would not be able to reuse the old url.

I am not really familiar with php, but I have been doing some research on it as I am seeking the ways to keep my links secure.

Comment: Use existing services such as bit.ly maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could generate the temporary keys to send with the URL, and when user lands on the page, the temporary key should be removed, then this current URL can't accessed again. You will have to generate unique keys for each user.

Comment: i see, so how can i generate this random key and let it knows this is the link for that file? actually this sounds like the way that all those download website have been using. i wish i could have this, too. any keywords for me to study on? or the best is that you can have an example. Thanks!!

Comment: i proposed a simple solution, you will generate a unique value and save it in db send this key as a query string. At the targeted page, check if the key was already generated, then authorize it and remove it. The key should also have a time stamp to check the auto expiration.

Comment: So sorry for the late picking up of this question, I was too busy and forgot to solve this issue... Anyway, I did this according to the answer and it did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to encrypt the user IP and add it to the url, 
send it to a redirect page where you check if the decrypted IP is the same as the user IP

if correct, redirect to the original download.

Comment: thanks for reply, i see, sounds cool..any keywords that i can study on?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score -1):

One method i would opt is, you can send a key primitive with the link,
i.e, consider your link is `http://foobar.com/x/link1/xxx`.

1. You can generate an encryption algorithm. (Let it use multiple levels of any standard encryption).
2. Now generate another algorithm for key generation. This algorithm you can keep on both sides.
3. Generate any random key text (key-primitive), apply key generation algorithm and get the Encryption key.
4. Encrypt your link, either append your key-primitive with the encrypted content with a delimiter, extract it at other end, generate the key from it, decrypt your link. Done.

I.e.

```
data_to_send= base64(encAlgrithm(your_link,keygenAlgrithm(key_primitive)))+delimiter+Base64(key_primitive)
```

Base64 is done only to avoid the delimiters occur in encrypted content.

The other end can do the reverse process.